# youtube embed single video loop with playlist shows twice the same video

Tags: video, youtube, embed, playlist

I am trying to embed a YouTube video with loop mode on, and to do so I have to set the playlist parameter otherwise it won't work:

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?#loop)

The problem is when I do so i get a playlist with 2 videos on it, the same video appearing twice, which produces a very bad visual effect since i want one video to loop endlessly.

Any suggestions on how to do so? Thanks

Here's my code:

```
<iframe width="600" height="338" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID/?playlist=VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white" 
frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the following information is actually documented somewhere, but I want share the discovery I made by making some tests in the URL for trying solve your "problem".

---

Saying this, you can remove your "problem" - *(which is: `displaying the same video twice`)* - by modifying the URL as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID_1/?playlist=VIDEO_ID_2&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white
```

Explanation:

- **`VIDEO_ID_1`**: Corresponds to the `videoId` intended to play continuously - *(in loop)*.
- **`VIDEO_ID_2`**: Corresponds to the `videoId` usted in the **`VIDEO_ID_1`**, BUT with the last letter changed. The idea is **set a `videoId` that does not exist**.

So, with the previous explanation, you can use the following video as an example:

> Video: [Stack Overflow is 10!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwS1r1mc888)
>
> videoId: `QwS1r1mc888`

The modified URL shows the following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/QwS1r1mc888?enablejsapi=1&loop=1&playlist=QwS1r1mc880&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white
```

> N.B that the videoId `QwS1r1mc880` does not exist *(yet)* - you could also replace this value for `15874598752` - which will never be a YouTube `videoId` *(as far as I know)*.

---

Side note: I really hope this discovery won't be removed.