# Inconsistent behavior with loop=1 on iframe

Tags: youtube-api

I am having a very frustrating experience trying to get videos to loop consistently using a basic iframe.  I am not interacting with the API via code.  I simply have an iframe with `autoplay=1,mute=1,loop=1`.  I've tried using stand-alone videos and I've tried playlists (with `list=`[ID]`,listType=playlist`) and I keep running into the same problem.  Sometimes the player will loop the video and sometimes it will not.  Every time I think I have it figured out and I'm ready to deploy the app, I test it again and the video fails to loop.

Windows 10

Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Angular 6.0.3

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of these options:

- [Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356392/4092887) where I described how you can set your URL for create a playlist *(using a single `videoId`)* and simulate a loop.
- Use the YouTube iframe Player API for set your video and *(once the video ended)*, call the [`playVideo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#playVideo) function for play the current video = hence, creating a loop.

This is the code: - unfortunately, you can't see it working here, but, you can see the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/7zndco8r/1/)<sup>1</sup>

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Variables of the divs (where the YouTube iframe will load):
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  // Div player:
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'xPCZEoGJi_4',
    playerVars: {
      'autoplay': 1,
      'loop': 1,
      'mute': 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  // When the video ends, it will play again.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Events
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.playVideo();
  }
}

// Div "player" - The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If the video *(once has loaded)* hasn't play, you have to play manually the video - this is due some kind of restrictions that jsfiddle has.