# The loop tag doesn't work for this video in brackets

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple login page with a video as the background. The video should loop, be muted, not be able to be controlled by the user, and have all the usual youtube overlays hidden. This is the code I used to try and get that result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.login-info p {
  margin-bottom: -13px;
}

.login-details {
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 150%;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.background {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-MKapbz0GIo?loop=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
                </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="login-details">
    <form method="post" class="login-info">
      <p>Email:</p><br>
      <input id="Name" type="email" name="email" required="required"> <br>

      <p>Password:</p><br>
      <input id="Password" type="password" name="password" required="required"><br><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop parameter not working on youtube embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620997/loop-parameter-not-working-on-youtube-embed)

Comment: yes this answers the question. thank you. but also how can the user still control the video when controls is set to 0 and showinfo is also set to 0?

Comment: That's a different question. Don't ask questions here in the comment section. Open a new one.