# YouTube iframe looping video unavailable on first load

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

I embed a video on a Blazor-powered static page. I want the video to loop. According to docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), I need to have both `loop` and `playlist` params. Easy enough.

So I generate URL like this: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/tFbVZCbLhOk?autoplay=1&loop=1&modestbranding=1&disablekb=1&playsinline=1&rel=0&fs=0&playlist=tFbVZCbLhOk&controls=1&origin=http://localhost:5134 - as you can see, `loop` is set to `1`, and `playlist` is set to the same video itself `tFbVZCbLhOk`.

The problem I am having is that when the video is embedded (or the link is accessed directly - the issue occurs there as well), it errors with `This video is unavailable`. Refreshing the page fixes that, however it of course is less than perfect. I am not sure what causes this, as some videos appear to randomly work on first attempt - but it's inconsistent, cause the same video might fail other time.

Removing the `playlist` param fixes the issue, but then the video doesn't loop properly, which is even worse for my use case.

I am not sure if it's a regression on YouTube's side, as a month or two ago, I did not have that issue - I think so at least.
It also seems like it's not bound to the tab or anything like that - when I open video once, next time I open it on a separate tab, it works - almost like if YT took its sweet time to create playlist for the video, but that's just my guess

Comment: Did you happen to come to any resolution here?

Comment: Good thing you reminded me of this.
It resolved by itself. Guess it was just a YT-side error. I'll post an answer to mark as resolved.

Comment: I am still having this issue (so it didn't automatically resolve in my case).  I didn't have this issue in the past, so it is definitely a regression on YouTube's side.  As workaround I have removed the `playlist` param like you have suggested (I can live with the fact that it is not looping).

Comment: @JanVdA and TelFiRE - I just checked my project, and you're right - it appears it's broken again. Seems YouTube reintroduced this bug. I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your video sample (*i.e. **`tFbVZCbLhOk`***) and with the following code (*which I modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356392/12511801)*), and the looping of the video works fine:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/tFbVZCbLhOk?enablejsapi=1&loop=1&playlist=tFbVZCbLhOk&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white
```

Probably what you're describing is another YouTube undocumented change.

Comment: Yeah, it does loop - thanks to both `playlist` and `loop` being present. The issue is that when `playlist` is present, the video sometimes shows as unavailable on first load.
I tried adding `enablejsapi` and `showinfo` as in your example, but the effect sadly is the same.

For reference, the application loads one of the videos from the list at random, not constantly the same video - which makes the issue way more noticeable. You can see this here: https://randominator.tehgm.net/player

Comment: @TehGM well, in that case, I suggest you to see in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) if someone else has this problem or you can post there the issue as well. I bet this is some sort of undocumented change or the petition(s) are blocked for your page. Check also the console "press F12" and see if any problem/error shows. (consider check the "navigation" tab as well.

Comment: As for now there is already reported bug on this specific issue, but unresolved sadly: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249707272

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe onload="this.src+='';this.onload='';"
```

This reload once the iframe and after that it stops. I hope it will help you.