# Youtube iframe looped video not working on first load

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

I'm embedding a video on my website from YouTube and I want it to loop. To do that I have to use the loop and playlist parameters. I do that and it generates a link like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/MegurLP8PxI?playlist=MegurLP8PxI&autoplay=1&controls=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&start=312&loop=1&widgetid=55. So the loop parameter is set to 1 and the playlist is set to the video id MegurLP8PxI.

The issue is that when I initially load the video it shows the This video is unavailable error. Refreshing the page fixes that but that's not ideal. What makes it hard to understand what's wrong is that this only happens sometimes, seemingly at random. Happens with other videos too.

Another fix that I found is removing the playlist parameter from the url. However than the video will not loop, which I really need it to. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71858565/12511801).